# Three way binding (two of TwoWay binding). Is it possible?

Tags: wpf, binding, master-detail

I'm new to data binding, so perhaps this question will seem rather stupid.
I use Xceed WPF Toolkit's DataGridControl which i got from http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/ Which I think is very similar to a DataGrid control in usage. I intend to bind the DataGridControl SelectedItem to a Grid contents. The related controls and object variables are:

```
GridKaryawan --> DataGridControl
Grid --> without name, for displaying details
karyawans --> ObservableCollection<BiodataKaryawan> --> collection of business objects
selKaryawan --> (intended to be) the selected business object
* The business object "BiodataKaryawan" has already implemented INFC.
```

So far I've been doing (only the relevant part shown):

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="GridKaryawan" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=karyawans}" ReadOnly="True" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selKaryawan, Mode=TwoWay}">
    ....
    ....
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

At code behind:

```
    public ObservableCollection<BiodataKaryawan> karyawans { get; set; }
    public BiodataKaryawan selKaryawan { get; set; }
```

And at the grid:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=selKaryawan, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
       <ColumnDefinition />
       ....
       ....
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
       ....
       ....
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0">Nama:</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1">Panggilan:</Label>
    ....
    ....

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txtNama" Text="{Binding Nama}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="txtPanggilan" Text="{Binding Panggilan}" />
    ....
    ....
</Grid>
```

I've successfully bound the DataGridControl.SelectedItem to the Grid. But I want to bind them using a "selKaryawan" object at the code behind, since the form will also support creating new "BiodataKaryawan", and I intend to use a button "Create New" to assign a new BiodataKaryawan object to selKaryawan.
But the binding failed. When i selected a row at the datagrid, the details did not show as when i bound it to "GridKaryawan.SelectedItem". Where did I go wrong? or is it possible at all?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your codebehind and raise PropertyChanged event in setter of selKaryawan property